# How to migrate data in sqlite alembic migration?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a column `goods.visible` (boolean) and i want to replace it with `goods.status` (enum).

I need to replace one column with another and migrate data using sqlalchemy (to use its data type conversion mechanism). As sqlite does not support ALTER TABLE for this, I have to use `batch_alter_table` alembic operation for this.

My migration looks like the following. It throws `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: goods.status`, because in my old table there is no such column (new table is created for migration using batch)

```
def upgrade():
    with op.batch_alter_table('goods') as batch_op:
        batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('status', sa.Enum('published', 'unpublished', 'deleted'), nullable=True))

        conn = op.get_bind()
        Session = sa.orm.sessionmaker()
        session = Session(bind=conn)
        for good in session.query(Good):
            # I want to perform some data updates & insert data into new column
        batch_op.drop_column('visible')
```

If i will add `load_only` to specify columns to be selected from the table:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: goods.status`

i will get error `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named 'visible' on the mapped entity Mapper|Good|goods in this Query.`. I understand why i get it - i have no more property visible in my model.

How i can migrate data using alembic in this case?

I tried to use raw queries.. but it says there is no table:

```
    s = sa.sql.select([sa.sql.text('goods.*')])
    for row in conn.execute(s):
        print(row)
```

Hovewer inspector displays `goods` table:

```
 inspector = sa.inspect(conn.engine)
    for table_name in inspector.get_table_names():
        print(table_name)
        for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name):
            print("Column: %s" % column['name'])
```

Displays

```
goods
Column: id
Column: name
Column: price
Column: visible
```

Comment: Can't yet address the rest of your post, but the reason for `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: goods.status` seems to be that actually the batch operation [collects instructions registered through `batch_op`](http://alembic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html) within the `with` block and then at `__exit__` executes them. So within the with block there really is no *status* column yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple batch_alter_table blocks. Use the first one to add the new column, then (outside and after the block) run your business logic (in this case conversion of your boolean value to some enum values), then use another block to drop the column.

Something like:-

```
def upgrade():
    with op.batch_alter_table('goods') as batch_op:
        batch_op.add_column(sa.Column('status', sa.Enum('published', 'unpublished', 'deleted'), nullable=True))
    # Do your business logic here
    with op.batch_alter_table('goods') as batch_op:
        batch_op.drop_column('visible')
```